# Issue passing facebook data to View from routes.php

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel, laravel-4

Hi I am getting this error when I try to display data in my `view` in `laravel-4`. I am using the `Facebook SDK dev-master`

this is my `error:`

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp\www\irishrail.tld\app\views\user\authed.blade.php)
```

This is my `view:`

```
<div class="cover authed">
        <div class="profile">
            <div class="avatar">
                <img height="100%" width="100%" src="{{$cred->profile_image_url}}" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title-bar">
        Congrats {{$cred->name}}
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <form action="/" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="code" class="field" placeholder="Redemption Code">
            <button class="btn btn-green">Claim your ticket</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

This is my `route:`

```
Route::get('login/facebook/callback', function(){
    $code = Input::get('code');//error

    $facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();//Gets the user id

    //Get User Details from FB
    $credentials = $facebook->api('/me');
    $photo = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$uid.'/picture';

    $credentials['name'] = $credentials['first_name']." ".$credentials['last_name'];
    $credentials['profile_image_url'] = $photo;//Add photo to the credentials

    return View::make('user.authed')->with('cred', $credentials);
});
```

Comment: Looks like `$cred` is an array.  Try `$cred['profile_image_url']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your route you define `$credentials` as array, in your view you are accessing it via the object operator.

```
{{ $cred['name'] }}
```

should work for you in your view.

Another option would be to cast your array to an object. In your route, before you return the view, do

```
$credentials = (object) $credentials;
```

Then you are able to access the data in the view like in your example above.

btw, this has nothing to do with the facebook sdk or laravel, this is a plain php error.